# verify records exist within the same group

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, 1 with pairwise comparisons from 2 other datasets (A and B) and 1 with rows from those 2 other datasets but also a group ID indicating these rows have similar data and have been grouped together.

The pairwise comparison df looks like this:

```
origin_x  |  id_x    |  origin_y  |  id_y  |  ...
__________________________________________________
  A       |   13     |    B       |    7   |  ...
  A       |    2     |    B       |    5   |  ...
```

The grouping dataframe looks like this:

```
origin  |  id    |  group_id |  ...
_____________________________________
  A     |   13   |    A_13   |  ...
  B     |    7   |    A_13   |  ...
```

I want to check if certain rows in the pairwise comparison dataframe exist within the same group in the grouping dataframe. So if each pairwise row represents a relationship between 2 records (1 from dataset A and 1 from dataset B), I want to check that both records are present within 1 group (have the same `group_id`) in the grouping dataframe.

Whats the best way to go about verifying this?

Answer (score 0):

When you [.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the pair of dataframes,
be sure to specify `how='left'` outer join.
Notice how `None` group IDs in the result
indicate a mismatch across the pair.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but how could I merge this properly if each pairwise row represents 2 rows in the group dataframe?